# pagination with angular4 and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I try apply pagination in angular 4 and jquery but I have error when I click in next button it moving for first 2 pages and then moving 3 other pages and then moving 5 other pages( when click)..

code component:

```js
addClass(x) {
  $(".page-item").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass('current');
  });
}
```

```js
next() {
  $('.next').click(function () {
    $('.current').next('li').trigger('click');
  });
}
```

code html:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="previous">Previous</li>
  <li class="next" (click)="next()">Next</li>
</ul>

<ul class="pagination">
  <li *ngFor="let x of pages" class='page-item current' 
      (click)='addClass(x)'>{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

class current is add in when I click in page 5 for example but error class current it moving 2 pages for first click and next click moving 3 other pages and next click moving 5 pages

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? It's a bit unclear what the problem is. Also mixing Angular (click) handler and jQuery click handler, is that sound?

Comment: Pay at least the minimum amount of attention to formatting please, the code is hardly readable...

Comment: My problem if click in next and class current in 1 is moving to 3 (not to 2) .. it move to 2 but automaticly move to 3 and when click to 3 it move to 6 and also it to to 4 5 but automaticly move to 5

Comment: [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence). I think you should reset x on every page update. It seems the value of x gets added to the previous value of x. Your code is hard to understand (and why jQuery with Angular?), but what happens when you `console.log(x)` after a call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already binding the `click` event in your HTML template:

```html
<li class="next" (click)="next()">Next</li>
```

And in your component you're adding a new `click` handler on every click:

```
next()
{
   $('.next').click(function(){
     $('.current').next('li').trigger('click');
   });
}
```

So what you actually want to do is just relay that click in the method instead of adding a new handler:

```
next()
{
   $('.current').next('li').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: no idea how you understood what the guy wants from the current description of his problem.